# Need help regarding select DB for Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an application for attendance using SQLite DB, but for activation purposes, I am using Firebase for one time.
[image: This is my Firebase real-time DB]

And I am using this code to check the verified field is true or not.

```
                ref.child(activation_code).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            ActivationModel model = data.getValue(ActivationModel.class);
                            Log.d("++++++++++++", model.getCode());
                            Toast.makeText(Setup.this, ""+model.isVerified(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if(model==null){
                                Toast.makeText(Setup.this, "Enter Valid Code!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else{
                                if(model.isVerified()){
                                    Toast.makeText(Setup.this, "Code is already used, Please Enter valid code.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(Setup.this, "Code worked..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    ref.child(activation_code).child(activation_code).child("verified").setValue(true).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                                        Toast.makeText(Setup.this, "field changed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
                });
```

Now the problem is when entering valid code, so I am updating the `verified` to `true`, so firebase refreshes the data and check the condition again and create `Toast` of code already used.

Is there any way I can tackle this?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: There is no error in the code, but as realtime db sync data with application as changed in firebase, I am changing the field ```verified``` to true after valid activation code, but as soon as field changed the app refresh the code, and give me error, "code is already used, kindly enter valid code".